# Dell powerconnect 6224 vlan routing

Tags: routing, switch, vlan, dell, dell-powerconnect

I have a small network and I need help with routing .. .

My VLANs

VLAN 1010 SALES

VLAN 1020 HR

I have assigned the above vlans to a tagged port and I have added a default route to send the traffic of to my firewall.

***ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.10.10***

I have added a new vlan

VLAN 1030 Services

and I would like its traffic to go to a different interface on the firewall, 10.10.10.20

how can I go about doing that? can someone give me an example?

your help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is create a VRF, or another independent routing table for the other VLAN. I don't know if the 6224 has that feature or policy routing.  Another way to tackle this would be to route on the firewall, put the firewall 10.10.10.20 interface into VLAN 1030 and make the firewall the default gateway for that subnet.

Answer (score 0):

A more specific route will be chosen over the default route. So route 10.10.10.0 mask 255.255.255.0 interface 10.10.10.20 will be picked over a default route of 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 10.10.10.10.

Remember that your routing process doesn't care about your VLANs. All a router is going to do is think "What is the most specific route I have for this traffic, and what interface is identified in that route".